# Flume performance with memory channel

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

For 4gb data with below configuration its taking 3 mins. Is there a way to reduce time. What would be the best time that can be achieved? I dont think there is issue with hdfs sink but with either source or channel.

```
identify the components on agent memoryagent
memoryagent.sources = tr_source
memoryagent.sinks = tr_sink tr1_sink
memoryagent.channels = tr_channel

 Configure the source
memoryagent.sources.tr_source.type = spooldir
memoryagent.sources.tr_source.spoolDir = /home/apps/flumetest
memoryagent.sources.tr_source.deletePolicy = immediate
memoryagent.sources.tr_source.batchSize = 100000
memoryagent.sources.tr_source.deserializer.maxLineLength = 999999999
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.type = hdfs
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.path =  hdfspath/ymd=%Y%m%d
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.filePrefix = sink0
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.rollCount = 0
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.rollSize = 1600000000
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.batchSize = 100000
#memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.codeC = snappy
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.callTimeout = 30000
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.hdfs.threadsPoolSize = 20
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.type = hdfs
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.path = hdfspath/ymd=%Y%m%d
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.filePrefix = sink1
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.rollCount = 0
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.rollSize = 1600000000
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.batchSize = 100000
#memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.codeC = snappy
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.callTimeout = 30000
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.hdfs.threadsPoolSize = 20

Configure a channel that buffers events in file
memoryagent.channels.tr_channel.type = memory
memoryagent.channels.tr_channel.capacity = 999999999
memoryagent.channels.tr_channel.transactionCapacity = 99999999
memoryagent.channels.tr_channel.type.byteCapacity = 161061273600

Bind the source and sink to the channel
memoryagent.sources.tr_source.channels = tr_channel
memoryagent.sinks.tr1_sink.channel = tr_channel
memoryagent.sinks.tr_sink.channel = tr_channel
```

Comment: Is it a possibility to make multiple sources/channels? That way you could process events in parallel?